# Export DevExpress ASPXPivotGrid with themes

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, pivot-table

I am using DevExpress ASPXPivotGrid control for my ASP.NET site.I am also using DevExpress ASPXPivotGridExporter control to ASPXPivotGrid to different file formats. 
The problem I am having is that ASPXPivotGridExporter cannot export themes. Exported output always come out with default formating.
I would like to know if its possible to export pivot grid with theme? If not is there work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To customize a cell appearance during exporting, access and modify the e.Brick property (see the sample code snippet in the **ASPxPivotGridExporter.CustomExportCell** Event)...*

Review the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q327108 discussion in the DevExpress support center. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks seem @Mikhail Preyskurantov, that works for custome styling